# how to escape special characters in mysql jdbc connection string

Tags: mysql, jdbc, connection

im trying to connect to a remote database. im sure that the remote database provide me all the privileges. but im getting this error when trying to connect to the remote mysql database through `jdbc connection`. my password contains, `* and & symbol`, i think that is the problem cause to this `error`. but i dont know how to `escape those characters`. please help

```
java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'myusername'@'myhost' (using password: YES)

"jdbc:mysql://myhost/mydb?user=myusername&password=my&password*"
```

please help

Regards

Comment: you mean your password is (my&password*") ????

Comment: i) Try adding port to the server ii) http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/java/03cvhkkd6b/how-to-in-password

Comment: i tried with &amp; but it didnt work, and also i added port but it gave me same error.im using mysql 5.1.22 j connector.any other suggestions?

Answer (score 20):

The JDBC connection string is in url format so you must use URL encoded values for all parameters. In your case the connection string should look like:

```
"jdbc:mysql://myhost/mydb?user=myusername&password=my%26password%2A"
```

Answer (score 2):

[URLEncoder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) can be used:

```
String connectionString = "jdbc:mysql://myhost/mydb?" + URLEncoder.encode("user=myusername&password=my&password*", "UTF-8");
```