# jdbc connection from Apps Script to MySQL connection failure

Tags: javascript, mysql, jdbc, google-apps-script

I am attempting to connect to a hosted (not local) MySQL database using the Jdbc.getConnection method in Google apps script, but I'm repeatedly getting "failed to connect, check user name, password, etc" error messages when I attempt to test the connection, although I can connect successfully from a MySQL client.

I have whitelisted the Google apps script IP ranges in my Cpanel Remote MySQL settings, and I have even temporarily setup a wildcard "%" access host to allow everything, but cannot get the connection to work.

I can successfully connect to the database from my desktop PC using SQLyog from my desktop PC, so the server, database name, user, password, port, etc values are all correct, and I'm using these exactly as specified in the getConnection documentation.

I've tested the connection many times while experimenting with the connection values and whitelist rules, and the final twist is that on one solitary occasion, I connected successfully! However, all previous and all subsequent attempts have consistently failed.

The solitary successful call made me suspect that this is a whitelisting issue, and I just got lucky and got one call routed via a Google IP that my host finds acceptable. However, this doesn't square with the continued failure even when I use the simple % wildcard to allow anything.

Can anyone shed any light on what the problem could be, or suggest avenues for further investigation?

```
var conn = Jdbc.getConnection('jdbc:mysql://mydomain.com:3306/mydb','user','password');
```

Comment: Do you have special characters in your password? If so, you will need to use URL encoded values. See this other question/answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34308709/9533368

Comment: Does your sql have trace of the connection attempt and why it rejected the connection?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/making-trace-files.html

Comment: I'm not using the URL encoded format of the connection string (see code above) so I don't think the special characters issue applies here, but I tried changing the password anyway, and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: My database is hosted on a shared CPanel instance, so I don't have access to more detailed MySQL logging